# Progress bar stuck at 0 with inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, huggingface, tqdm

I have a really simple question, I am using HuggingFace's `transformers` to grab pretrained model from the hub, but the progress bar stuck at zero.

[image]

I have try several approaches such as:

- Reinstall `ipywidgets`
- Activate `widgetsnbextension`
- Restarting kernel
- Tried importing `tqdm` method from `tqdm.notebook` & `tqdm`

All I get was, if I make a simple loop with `tqdm` wrapper, the `tqdm.notebook` solution works, but downloading model (and also training API) just keep giving me the same stuck in zero thing.

[image]

Any helps or insights how might this happened?